# Executing a script under a specific user

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I have a script which runs as root (azure CustomScript vm extension) which launches another script (not maintained by me) that should configure a particular service to run under specific user (the user that the script was invoked by).

working dir `/downloads/0`

`drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Oct  6 08:50 0`

myscript.sh (run as root by vm extension)

```
#!/bin/bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-azure-pipelines-build-agent/main/build-agent.sh > build-agent.sh
chmod u+x build-agent.sh
sudo -E -u myuser./build-agent.sh
```

In theory this should achieve what I want, but my problem is that I get

> sudo: unable to execute ./build-agent.sh: Permission denied

I have tried:

```
chown myuser build-agent.sh
chmod u+x build-agent.sh
sudo -E -u myuser ./build-agent.sh
```

still got Permission denied, how do I configure permissions for this?
permissions after the last command:

```
ls -l build-agent.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 opsai root 1731 Oct  6 11:02 build-agent.sh
```

Comment: 1. Please show us the permissions and ownership of `build-agent.sh`. Edit the original question to add the output of `ls -l build-agent.sh`; 2. Can you add permissions to the working dir or if that is not possible, can you create a new working directory, where the standard user has read, write and execute permissions?

Comment: ```shell
ls -l build-agent.sh

-rwxr--r-- 1 myuser root 1731 Oct  6 11:02 build-agent.sh
```
working dir is temporary subdirectory where the stuff is being downloaded, so I guess there is no harm in changing permissions there, I guess creating new dir and `cd`ing there is also an option if that makes any difference.
@bac0n just a typo

Comment: Are you using `opsai` instead of `myuser` ? Anyway, I think it will work when you add permissions to the working directory.

Comment: forgot to replace that when editing text, but there is only one user and let's refer to it as "myuser".

Comment: OK - I was just checking (it is easy to forget such obvious things).

Comment: changing owner on working dir worked, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that I could help you find a solution :-)